# This is a TEST QUESTION, examining MathJax scopes

Tags: discussion, mathjax

```
\require{begingroup}
\begingroup
```

$
\require{begingroup}
\begingroup
\text{begingroup Jax}
\def\ce#1{\Huge\color{\purple}{\mathrm{I~love~chemistry!}}}
$

This is the body of the test question. There isn't actually anything here. I'm curious to see how many downvotes this gets.

Initial usage of `\frac`:

```
\frac{1}{2}
```

$
\frac{1}{2}
$

```
\endgroup
```

$
\endgroup
\text{endgroup Jax}
$

Comment: $\require{begingroup}\begingroup\def\frac#1#2{#2\over #1} \text{\xgroup protected Jax with redefine of \frac}\endgroup$ `\require{begingroup}\begingroup\def\frac#1#2{#2\over #1} \text{\xgroup protected Jax with redefine of \frac}\endgroup`

Comment: $\require{begingroup}\begingroup\endgroup\def\frac#1#2{#2\over #1} \text{\xgroup protected Jax with redefine of \frac, but blocked with extra \xgroups}\begingroup\endgroup$ `\require{begingroup}\begingroup\endgroup\def\frac#1#2{#2\over #1} \text{\xgroup protected Jax with redefine of \frac, but blocked with extra \xgroups}\begingroup\endgroup`

Comment: All that malicious content... $\def\text#1{\Huge\color{\red}{\mathrm{I~love~beer!}}}%Hahahaha!$

Comment: or is it here? $%...$

Comment: Maybe here ... $\def\text#1{\Huge\color{\red}{\mathrm{I~love~beer!}}}$

Comment: You can't really tell....

Comment: You would have to check ***every comment***. $\def\text#1{\Huge\color{\red}{\mathrm{I~love~maths!}}}$

Comment: And how would the ordinary user know how to look at it in the first place... $\def\text#1{\Huge\color{\green}{\mathrm{I~love~beer!}}}$

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Use the app, where MathJax in comments doesn't render. :)

Comment: @hBy2Py Downvoted for loving beer.

Comment: What are you talking about?$\def\text#1{\Huge\color{\purple}{\mathrm{I~love~chemistry!}}}$

Comment: @orthocresol In the app, since the comments are not rendered, there should not be any effect in the answers, too. And you still have to chuck every comment.... O.o

Comment: @Martin-マーチン That was sneaky.......! I just meant, if we are trying to find rogue mathjax, then we can just check the app. $\def\text#1{\Huge\color{\pink}{\mathrm{I~hate~chemistry!}}}$

Comment: Downvoted for not being provoking enough

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Hahaha, when it re-rendered the question after I edited it, the graffiti showed up there, too. :-)

Comment: $\renewcommand{\frac}{mathmeow}$ Hola.

Comment: Here is a nice fraction: $\frac{2}{3}$.

Answer (score 4):

```
\require{begingroup}
\begingroup
```

$
\require{begingroup}
\begingroup
\text{begingroup Jax}
$

Testing `\frac`:

```
\frac{1}{2}
```

$
\frac{1}{2}
$

```
\endgroup
```

$
\endgroup
\text{endgroup Jax}
$

Comment: Welcome to my world.

Answer (score 2):

**Text of non-problematic comment**

```
$\require{begingroup}\begingroup\def\frac#1#2{#2\over #1} \text{\xgroup protected Jax with redefine of \frac}\endgroup$ `\require{begingroup}\begingroup\def\frac#1#2{#2\over #1} \text{\xgroup protected Jax with redefine of \frac}\endgroup`
```

**Text of problematic comment**

```
$\require{begingroup}\begingroup\endgroup\def\frac#1#2{#2\over #1} \text{\xgroup protected Jax with redefine of \frac, but blocked with extra \xgroups}\begingroup\endgroup$ `\require{begingroup}\begingroup\endgroup\def\frac#1#2{#2\over #1} \text{\xgroup protected Jax with redefine of \frac, but blocked with extra \xgroups}\begingroup\endgroup`
```